# How to serialize to json format a queryset that use the 'extra' statement in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to serialize a QuerySet that contains an **extra** statement:

```
region_list = Region.objects.extra(select={ 'selected': 'case when id = %s then 1 else 0 end' % (new_region.id)}).all()
```

I use the statement below to serialize

```
return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize('json', region_list), mimetype='application/json')
```

But when I obtain the json results in the browser, only the fields of the Region model appears, the *selected* field dissapear.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

One *slightly* longwinded solution would be to to dump the objects to JSON via [django-piston](http://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home)'s JSONEmitter class. When you register your Region model with piston, you can say what fields to include, and mention 'selected' there, and then use your annotation to make sure that the queryset used in the piston handler contains all the info you want.

Or just look at how piston does it and, if you don't want all of piston, just mimic the bits you do.